# How to structure a class for use with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

I'm trying to populate a WPF datagrid using data from a SharePoint List.

I retrieve the list information with the following:

```
private void buttonRefreshOrders_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var ctx = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint"))
    {
        var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Resource Orders");

        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery
                                {
                                    ViewXml =
                                        @"<Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name=""Status""></FieldRef><Value Type=""Text"">Approved</Value></Eq><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name=""Status"" /></FieldRef></IsNotNull></Or></Where>"
                                };

        var collListItem = list.GetItems(query);

        ctx.Load(
            collListItem, 
            items => items.Include(
                item => item.Id, 
                item => item.DisplayName,      
                item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,
                item => item["Persona"]));

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        if (collListItem.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "No resource orders are currently within the queue.", 
                "Information Center", 
                MessageBoxButton.OK, 
                MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success!");

            foreach (var item in collListItem)
            {
                CustomersCollection.Add(new Customers { Persona = item["Persona"].ToString() });
            }

            dataGridOutstandingOrders.ItemsSource = CustomersCollection;
        }
    }

}
```

And I've created an observable collection using the following:

```
public ObservableCollection<Customers> CustomersCollection { get; set; }
```

And my Customers class looks like this:

```
public class Customers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the persona.
    /// </summary>
    public string Persona { get; set; }
}
```

I'm receiving `System.NullReferenceException` on the following line:

```
CustomersCollection.Add(new Customers { Persona = item["Persona"].ToString() });
```

Which I anticipate is something not being properly initialized with my customers class, but I'm not entirely sure how to fix this or what to research. What's the missing piece here?

Comment: Where do you initialize the collection?  Properties are not initialized automatically...

Comment: @RonBeyer How do I tackle this? I thought this was the case for an auto property?

Comment: @RonBeyer OH! Sorry I understand now, thank-you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue here is that item["Persona"] is null.

Your customers code looks fine.

Edit:  Opps,  your not initialising your collection. so when you call it,  your trying to put a customer into a null.

you need to instantiate and instance of ObservableCollection

so you have declared it as a property of lets assume Class xyz. you therefore need to in your code above use it as follows

```
xyz stuff = new xyz();
stuff.CustomersCollection = new ObservableCollection<Customers>();
stuff.CustomersCollection.add(new customer("blah"));
```

alternatively,  declare the initialisation in the create method of xyz so it instanciates a new instance of the collection on object creation.

Comment: I've tested this in debugging, item["Persona"] is definitely not null.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing! I was too busy thinking about auto-properties... Thank-you!